displacement node doesn't work
After tracking a movie clip, the tracking setup plane is used as the structure to create a crater.
Issue one: the sim plane is visible in Material Preview mode but not in Render Preview mode.
Issue two: the displacement node does not work on the plane (using Cycles) in either Material or Render Previews. Am using "displacement only."
However, if I create this same node setup and apply it to a plane without a movie clip (and tracking), the sim works! A crater is created in the plane. Displacement node works.


Displacement node only works in Rendered view, not in Material Preview. For the rest it would be good if you would at least show a few screenshots of your settings. Or upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

A "solution" to my displacement issue: replace the tracking setup plane with a new plane. The new plane seems to work as expected. Hope this helps someone. And thanks for Gordon for you comments.
